# How do I add columns to a list of dataframes using paste0() in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply, purrr, mapply

I have a list of 2 dataframes called list_of_sheets. These dataframes are data from Excel sheets which have identical column names. Below is a snapshot of the relevant columns.

```
List of 2
 $ :Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   242 obs. of  43 variables:
  ..$ Market Section     : num [1:242] 559286 559287 559286 559287 559287 ...
  ..$ Market Section Name: chr [1:242] "DOMESTIC BULK CUSTOMER MARKET SECTION" "INTERNATIONAL BULK MARKET SECTION" "DOMESTIC BULK CUSTOMER MARKET SECTION" "INTERNATIONAL BULK MARKET SECTION" ...
  ..$ JDE Branch Plant   : chr [1:242] "PBK0100" "PBK0200" "PBK0200" "PNR0100" ...
  ..$ Short Item Code    : num [1:242] 2085010 1782171 1782059 1823261 1934471 ...
  ..$ Long Item Code     : chr [1:242] "016144" "637524" "554326" "149226" ...
```

I am trying to create a Key column which would be a concatenation of the JDE Branch Plant, Long Item Code, and Market Section columns.

Below are some approaches I have tried. I am a beginner in R and my knowledge of using the apply() functions and working with lists is limited, so I appreciate any help provided. I imagine I am making an obvious mistake to those with more experience.

```
list_of_sheets <- mapply(cbind, list_of_sheets, "Key" = paste0(`JDE Branch Plant`, `Long Item Code`, `Market Section`))

for (i in seq_along(list_of_sheets)) {
  list_of_sheets[[i]]$Key <- paste0(`JDE Branch Plant`, `Long Item Code`, `Market Section`)

  }
```

For both of these, I get the following error.

```
Error in paste0(`JDE Branch Plant`, `Long Item Code`, `Market Section`) : 
  object 'JDE Branch Plant' not found
```

I believe there may also be a purrr solution, but I don't know much about the package. 
If anyone has recommended resources to deeply understand the apply and purrr functions in R, I would appreciate that also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is a `tbl_df`, we can use `tidyverse` approaches i.e. loop over the `list` with `map`, create the 'Key' column by `unite`ing the relevant columns while specifying the `remove = FALSE` (if those columns are no longer needed, by default, it is `remove = TRUE`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
list_of_sheets2 <- list_of_sheets %>%
     map(~ .x %>%
                unite(Key, `JDE Branch Plant`,
             `Long Item Code`, `Market Section`, remove = FALSE, sep=""))
```

---

In the OP's code, the issue is that it is just `paste`ing the column names instead of the values in those columns.  We can extract the columns of each of the dataset with `[[`

```
for (i in seq_along(list_of_sheets)) {
    list_of_sheets[[i]]$Key <- paste0( list_of_sheets[[i]][["JDE Branch Plan"]],  
     list_of_sheets[[i]][["Long Item Code"]], 
     list_of_sheets[[i]][["Market Section"]])

 }
```

Or it can be made a bit shorter using `with`

```
for (i in seq_along(list_of_sheets)) {
    list_of_sheets[[i]]$Key <-
         with(list_of_sheets[[i]], paste0(`JDE Branch Plant`,
          `Long Item Code`, `Market Section`))

   }
```

---

The OP also tried with `mapply` and have the same issue.  In this case, we don't need `mapply` as `Map/mapply` are used for transformations with corresponding elements.  Here, each of the `list` element have the same column and needs transformation for those same columns.  Instead, it can be done with `lapply`

```
list_of_sheets2 <- lapply(list_of_sheets, transform,
        Key = paste0(`JDE Branch Plant`, `Long Item Code`, `Market Section`))
```

Comment: thanks very much for your help. These solutions worked nicely, although I couldn't get the first for loop to work. R couldn't find the column names. Just for my learning purposes, I was curious why you used transform() in the lapply solution. I looked it up in the Help section but wasn't sure.

Comment: @LauraDR Sorry, I didn't test it as there was no reproducible example.  Can you change the updated code i.e. changing backquotes to single or double quotes for the column name in that `for` loop

Comment: @LauraDR  the `transform` was to avoid the use of anonymous function call ie..  `lapply(list_of_sheets, function(dat) {dat$Key <- with(dat, paste0(`JDE Branch Plant`, `Long Item Code`, `Market Section`)); dat})` as `transform` can directly evaluate if we give unquoted column names (if there are spaces or unnatural names, then use backquotes)'